# Segmentation fault (core dumped) when making compliation

Tags: assembly, compilation, compiler-construction

I was solving assignment that involve creating small Compiler. My compiler produce the following assembly code for simple assignment statement

```
// global declaration
int k;

float x,y,z;
// inside main func
k=10;
x = y = k;
```

Assembly code (I'm **getting Segmentation fault (core dumped)** :

```
 #   19
                    # b_push_ext_addr (x)
        subl    $8, %esp
        movl    $x, (%esp)
                    # b_push_ext_addr (y)
        subl    $8, %esp
        movl    $y, (%esp)
                    # b_push_ext_addr (k)
        subl    $8, %esp
        movl    $k, (%esp)
                    # b_deref (signed int)
        movl    (%esp), %eax

# Proplm on next Line ... why?
         movl (%eax), %edx


        movl    %edx, (%esp)
                    # b_convert (signed int -> float)
        fildl   (%esp)
        fstps   (%esp)
                    # b_assign (float)
        movl    (%esp), %edx
        addl    $8, %esp
        movl    (%esp), %eax
        movl    %edx, (%eax)
        movl    %edx, (%esp)
                    # b_deref (float)
        movl    (%esp), %eax
        movl    (%eax), %edx
        movl    %edx, (%esp)
                    # b_convert (float -> double)
        flds    (%esp)
        fstpl   (%esp)
                    # b_convert (double -> float)
        fldl    (%esp)
        fstps   (%esp)
                    # b_assign (float)
        movl    (%esp), %edx
        addl    $8, %esp
        movl    (%esp), %eax
        movl    %edx, (%eax)
        movl    %edx, (%esp)
                    # b_pop ()
        addl    $8, %esp
```

When I used gdb: it point to this line:

```
(gdb) x/i $eip
=> 0x80485bd <main+336>:        mov    (%eax),%edx
```

Comment: To be clear, do you mean that the code your compiler generates dies with a segmentation fault when you run it?

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong, you should learn to use a debugger to at least identify the faulting instruction.

Comment: @Keith Thompson Yes, it dies when i run the generated executable code.

Comment: @Jester I'n new to this. Which debugger I use for assembly code.

Comment: Depends on platform and what you are familiar with. On linux the default is `gdb`, but some people can't handle it ;)

Comment: @Jester Yes, I'm using Linux

Comment: If you are not familiar with it, a few commands to get you going: `run` to run your code  and when it stops at the fault you can do `x/i $eip` to see the faulting instruction and `info registers` to show all registers. Everything else, use the `help` command ;)

Comment: @Jester ... Thank you

Comment: @Jester It shows that the issue with this command: (gdb) x/i $eip
=> 0x80485bd <main+336>:        mov    (%eax),%edx

Comment: You didn't show how `k` is declared.

Comment: @Jester  k=10; I also made an edit above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual fault is at a similar instruction but further down:

```
    fstps   (%esp)       # stack has some float
                # b_assign (float)
    movl    (%esp), %edx # edx has a float now
    addl    $8, %esp
    movl    (%esp), %eax
    movl    %edx, (%eax)
    movl    %edx, (%esp) # write the float onto stack
                # b_deref (float)
    movl    (%esp), %eax # load the float from stack
    movl    (%eax), %edx # try to use float as pointer => segfault
```

Comment: Thank you very much ... it worked... although, I'm not quite sure why it end to have float there, I suppose to have pointer to float.